# Unable to select value from the auto populated values for the second field in the application using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below Code is working fine for the first field in the application and the same code is not working for the second field. If we execute only second field steps able to see the expected output. Tried with all types of waits. but unable to resolve it. Can someone please look into below code and suggest me what I did wrong.

```
package com.qa.base;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Sample {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\Avanthi\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.abhibus.com/");

        // driver.findElement(By.id("source")).sendKeys("adi");
        driver.findElement(By.id("source")).sendKeys("Bang");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                .visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item']//parent::li")));

        List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item']//parent::li"));

        System.out.println("Auto Suggest List ::" + list.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());

            if (list.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Bangalore Kempegowda Intl Airport")) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
                list.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }

        try {
            driver.findElement(By.id("destination")).sendKeys("Chen");
            WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
            wait1.until(ExpectedConditions
                    .visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item']//parent::li")));
            List<WebElement> goingtolist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item']//parent::li"));
            System.out.println("Auto Suggest List ::" + goingtolist.size());

            for (int i = 0; i < goingtolist.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(goingtolist.get(i).getText());

                if (goingtolist.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Chengannur Railway Station")) {
                    System.out.println(goingtolist.get(i).getText());
                    goingtolist.get(i).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Got the solution for above code

Comment: Xpath for second field i have updated :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. You may need to edit your question based on these guidelines. When you find the answer to your question, please write a full answer instead of a comment.

Comment: But when I tried to copy-paste complete code is not acceptable in the comment section.

Comment: I hope you figured out the solution yourselves. Cool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.qa.base;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Sample {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\Avanthi\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.abhibus.com/");


        driver.findElement(By.id("source")).sendKeys("Bang");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                .visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item']//parent::li")));

        List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item']//parent::li"));

        System.out.println("Auto Suggest List ::" + list.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());

            if (list.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Bangalore Kempegowda Intl Airport")) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
                list.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }

        try {
            driver.findElement(By.id("destination")).sendKeys("Chen");
            WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
            wait1.until(ExpectedConditions
                    .visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item']//parent::ul//following::ul//li")));
            List<WebElement> goingtolist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item']//parent::ul//following::ul//li"));
            System.out.println("Auto Suggest List ::" + goingtolist.size());

            for (int i = 0; i < goingtolist.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(goingtolist.get(i).getText());

                if (goingtolist.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Chengannur Railway Station")) {
                    System.out.println(goingtolist.get(i).getText());
                    goingtolist.get(i).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```